Unable to Setup Xcode Cloud
I click to Next button on Grand Access to Your Source Code step of setup screen

and in few seconds I am getting an error alert

I checked the requests (by Proxyman) that Xcode sends to a server and found that Xcode sends request to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ci/api/teams/.../apps/find?bundle_id= and receives status 401 Unauthorized. After that Xcode sends request to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ci/auth/auth/authkit and get jwt token and requests to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ci/api/teams/.../apps/find?bundle_id=... and receives status 401 Unauthorized again and shows the alert.
I sent a feedback about that to Apple and get response Please verify that your Apple ID session within Xcode has not expired, then try signing into your Apple ID account again.
I several times signed out and signed in to my Apple ID via Xcode and revoked and gave access to my GitHub repository for Xcode but it doesn't help me.
My Xcode is configured with our GitHub account.
How do I proceed?
